# Pass value into generator using for of loop

Tags: javascript

When iterating over a generator using a `for of` loop, is there a way to, pass a value back to the generator?

In the following code, when I call `iterable.next('some value')` manually, I can pass a value back, but the `for of` loop seems to call the `.next()` method without any value.

I hope I've explain this in an understandable way.

```
const test = function* generator() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  for (const x of list) {
    const data = yield x
    console.log(data)
  }
}
const iterable = test()
console.log(iterable.next())
console.log(iterable.next('test2'))

console.log('FOR OF LOOP')
for (const y of iterable) {
  console.log(y)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass something back in, you need to be in charge of calling `next()` you can't just delegate it to the `for…of`.

It's idiomatic to do this with a `while` loop, but you can also do it with a `for` loop. For example:

```js
const test = function* generator() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  for (const x of list) {
    const data = yield x
    console.log("passed in value: ", data)
  }
}
const iterable = test()
console.log('FOR OF LOOP')
let message = 0
for (let y = iterable.next(); !y.done; y = iterable.next(++message)) {
  console.log(y.value)
}
```

Or a `while` loop:

```js
const test = function* generator() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  for (const x of list) {
    const data = yield x
    console.log("passed in value: ", data)
  }
}

const iterable = test()
let message = iterable.next()
while(!message.done){
  console.log(message.value)
  message = iterable.next("some value")
}
```